# vTiger create activity meeting from custom workflow

Tags: vtiger

In vtiger open source, client wants to create a meeting invite on calendar once certain conditions are satisfied.  is there any method/api exposed in vtiger to which we can pass the event parameters and it will create the event?How to create meeting event from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create an Activity once conditions are satisfied. Set his arguments to those you want and then do an `Activity->save()`

Other option is to create the event directly on the database (you could do it through a query from the PHP code)